How can I override child parent inheritance in react native (JSX)?
I have a ScrollView and within it Text. I'd like the ScrollView to have 0.4 opacity and for the Text inside it to have full opacity (1).
My problem is that because of inheritance the child component inherits the 0.4 opacity. How can I fix it?
return (
<ScrollView horizontal style={[styles.scrollContainer, {backgroundColor: graphColour}]}>
        <View style={{opacity: 1}}>
          <Text style={[styles.scrollText, { color: textColour, opacity: 1}]}>{(hourlyData ?? []).slice(0, 24).map((hour, index) => (
          <Text key={index}>{hour.time}     </Text>))}</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollContainer: {
    width: 335,
    height: 130,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 320,
    opacity: 0.4,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10
  },
  scrollText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    opacity: 1,
  }
});

export default App;


You can set scrollview backgroundColor with transparency. E.g. "#FF0000" to "#FF000066" means red in color with 40% transparency.
